# Unreal Torunament (UT99) no sound in 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, sound, games, pulseaudio

I've been trying to get sound working in Unreal Torunament for a couple of days now.

I'm using the native Unreal Tournament version, not wine or something like that.
I have sound in all other games and media applications that I have tried.

In older ubuntu versions it worked fine. I'm now using kubuntu 12.04, I have all the alsa-oss and oss-compat packages installed.

I have followed most of the advice out there, and it all seems to fall on padsp and aoss.

My problem, however, is that even when trying to use `padsp` or `aoss`, I can't get any sound at all.

(Note UT has two output modes: `ALAudio` and `Generic`(OSS), I have tried both).

Is there some configuration required to use padsp or aoss correctly?

I have ran it like `padsp ./ut` and `aoss ./ut`

If using the AL backend in UT I get (both aoss and padsp give this):
`Bound to ALAudio.so`
`open /dev/dsp: Invalid argument`
`Audio initialization failed.`

If using the OSS backend in UT I get (both aoss and padsp give this):
`Bound to Audio.so`
`Failed to open audio device.`
`Audio initialization failed.`

Note that so far, I have gotten absolutely no sound.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, after trying and failing a lot I finally have sound in Unreal Tournament. It also runs at the right speed, so no more problems! Here are the important things I did:

In `~/.loki/ut/System/UnrealTournament.ini` :

```
;AudioDevice=ALAudio.ALAudioSubsystem
AudioDevice=Audio.GenericAudioSubsystem
```

In `UnrealTournament/bin/x86/ut` (note this file should be where you installed UT),
line 84 should read:

```
exec padsp "./ut-bin" -log $*
```

Thus running the executable with `padsp`, I have tried `aoss` here also, didn't work.

---

I think though, after several upgrades of my ubuntu install. That my sound setup have completely borked itself.

I followed [this Ubuntu Forums post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=11576732&postcount=2) to delete all my pulseaduio configuration (or misconfiguration):

```
$ rm -r ~/.pulse ~/.asound* ~/.pulse-cookie
sudo rm /etc/asound.conf
```

You should probably make a backup of these files before attacking them. In addition, I reinstalled the pulseaudio packages and removed the `alsa-oss` package. Note however that this was probably not required.

Hope this can help someone else!

Answer (score 2):

`padsp` did not work for me on XUbuntu 18.04 64-bit.  I got an error about ELF class:

> ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pulseaudio/libpulsedsp.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64): ignored.

If you look at the `/usr/bin/padsp` file (it's a BASH script) you will see that [it specifically refers to the x86_64 library](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=845802).  That link suggests creating a second `padsp32` script, but since this is such a unique binary, I decided to copy and paste the relevant code into the script that calls `ut-bin`, with modifications to use i386.

First, make sure you have the i386 version of libpulsedsp:

```
sudo apt-get install libpulsedsp:i386
```

Then edit the script you use to launch UT (mine is at `/usr/local/games/ut/ut`) and place these lines before the call to `ut-bin` (or in my case a variable that contains "ut-bin"):

```
if [ x"$LD_PRELOAD" = x ] ; then
   LD_PRELOAD="/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/pulseaudio/libpulsedsp.so"
else
   LD_PRELOAD="$LD_PRELOAD /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/pulseaudio/libpulsedsp.so"
fi
export LD_PRELOAD
```

I should also mention that, while using ALAudioSubsystem causes a substantial delay in audio, when I try the GenericAudioSubsystem, the game crashes.  The best workaround I've found so far is to edit `~/.loki/ut/System/UnrealTournament.ini` and, under `[ALAudio.ALAudioSubsystem]`, replace `Latency=40` with `Latency=0`.  This does not eliminate the audio delay, but significantly decreases it.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, it helped me here because padsp was looking for the 64bit and the changes in the script fixed it. On my 18.04 however, `GenericAudioSubsystem` doesn't crash so I use it instead of `ALAudioSubsystem` which still causes delay.

Answer (score 1):

Try to install osspd:

```
sudo apt-get install osspd
```

or from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/osspd/).

I had the same problem with Heroes 3 and Rune, and just find this package in synaptic. Now all sound related issues gone. You can run any older OSS app with it, and don't need to apply any file tweaks or command line option, just install it and run the application or game you want.